# Square Retrofit: Exception converting byte[]

Tags: exception, byte, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to get some data from my WebAPI REST service. However my model contains a byte[] and this leads to an exception.

The exception I receive looks like this:

```
Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 122 path $.Photo
```

This exception appears because my model has a byte[] called Photo.

My model:

```
public class Artists {
    private long ID;
    private String Firstname;
    private String Lastname;
    private String Description;
    private String Countrycode;
    private byte[] Photo;
    private java.util.Date Born;
    private java.util.Date Death;
    private java.util.Date Edited;
```

My REST API Java interface:

```
public interface ArtistRestService {
    @GET("/artist/{id}")
    Artists getArtist(@Path("id") long artistID);

    @GET("/artist")
    List<IdEditedRestObj> getArtists();
}
```

I know that I could use retrofit.mime.TypedByteArray but I also use GreenDAO an ORM mapper and I do not feel like to refactor the whole stack.

Is there an simple workaround/solution so I can somehow parse the incoming json so that exception does no take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:
Using https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/jackson/src/main/java/retrofit/converter/JacksonConverter.java

```
public RestService(String url){
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(getClient()))
                .setEndpoint(url)
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter())
                .setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler())
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.HEADERS_AND_ARGS)
                .build();
    }
```

Everything works fine now, thx

Comment: Accept your answer. :)